# How can I encrypt my ValidationExpression in VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, validation, encryption

I'm very new to asp and vb.net, I've just learned about regular expression validation but one thing is bugging me: How can I hide my expression from being viewed on my source code?

The plan is to make a very simple 'login' type of page. I know this goes against all that is holy in this kind of operations, but it's just something I'd like to try out.

Also, after the expression has been validated, I want to load another page, I was thinking of achieving this with:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CP Errada"
            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtcp" ValidationExpression="admin"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and in vb:

```
If txtcp is validated then
Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx")
end if
```

But the syntax on this IF is obviously not right, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the size of your Regex Validator by using the following.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcp" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" />
```

And then in your Code behind

```
Function Page_Load()
    With RegularExpressionValidator1
        .ErrorMessage="CP Errada"
        .Display="Dynamic" 
        .ControlToValidate="txtcp"
        .ValidationExpression="admin"
    End With
End Function

Function SubmitButton_Clicked()
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx")
    End If
End Function
```

Unfortunately you can't encrypt it since the whole point of validation is to use Client Side Javascript.  It is bad (in fact VERY BAD) to use a regular expression to validate a username in the way that I 'think' you're doing it in your example.  The right thing to do for you, honestly, is to just use the build in [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx). It is seriously easy to learn, it's mostly secure by default, and best of all... it's "no Fuss, no Muss".